# Start 3 windows services at a time with delay between them

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I am new to PowerShell and I need to write a script to start 3 or more windows services, in a specific order, with a set delay between them. I know how to write the script to start all of them, but I have no idea how to set the delay:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName cumputer_name -Name service_name1 | Stop-Service -Verbose
Get-Service -ComputerName cumputer_name -Name service_name2 | Stop-Service -Verbose
```

Comment: Use [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7) to create a delay.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `Start-Sleep`.

```
Get-Service -ComputerName cumputer_name -Name service_name1 | Stop-Service -Verbose
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Get-Service -ComputerName cumputer_name -Name service_name2 | Stop-Service -Verbose
```